# Alternative to using get_avatar function?

Tags: avatar

I used a WP hack for displaying author's pics. For example, my single.php has an author slug which displays the author's pic.

I created a folder called authors in my theme/images folder. Based on the author's ID, I name the file 1.jpg, 2.jpg and so on.

So I call this image as

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/images/authors/<?php the_author_ID()?>.jpg" alt="<?php the_author(); ?>">
```

Now i'm modifying a plugin that displays the authors in the sidebar. However this plugin uses the get_avatar function, which is as follows:

```
/**
                 * If show avatar option is checked, add get_avatar function to cache.
                 */
                if($jmetc_options['show_avatar'] == 1) {
                    $jmevar['cache'] .= get_avatar($tc->comment_author_email, $jmetc_options['avatar_size']);
                }
```

Can someone advise me on how to use/modify the get_avatar in order to use the default code that I use?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Chip.. i get a Unexpected '.' error in the function though

Comment: Ok, had to remove the ; after get_template_uri.. so now that its fixed.. still not able to see the changes made. I used `apply_filters('get_avatar', $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt);` replacing with get_avatar($tc and so on

Comment: You should comment in my *answer*, so I get notified when you comment. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `get_avatar()` function applies a `get_avatar` filter hook, that you can use to change the avatar markup:

```
return apply_filters('get_avatar', $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt);
```

I *think* this would be the correct way to hook into this filter:

```
function mytheme_get_avatar( $avatar ) {
    $avatar = '<img src="<' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/authors/' . get_the_author_ID() . '.jpg" alt="' . get_the_author() . '">';
    return $avatar;
}
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'mytheme_get_avatar' );
```

**EDIT**

p.s. a nice alternative to this approach might be the [Simple Local Avatars](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-local-avatars/) Plugin.

**EDIT 2**

The filter is applied using `add_filter()`, not `apply_filters()`. That was a typo on my part; fixed now!

**EDIT 3**

I don't think this is correct:

> P.S: Just to clarify.. I replaced
>   `get_avatar($tc->comment_author_email, $jmetc_options['avatar_size']);`
>   with `add_filter('get_avatar', $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default,
>   $alt);`

First, you still call `get_avatar()` in your template file, passing all the same parameters as previous. The `add_filter()` call belongs in `functions.php`.

Second, you can pass additional parameters to your filter function; e.g.:

```
function mytheme_get_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size ) {
    $avatar = '<img src="<' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/authors/' . $id_or_email . '.jpg" alt="' . get_the_author() . '" width="' . $size . 'px" height="' . $size . 'px" />';
    return $avatar;
}
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'mytheme_get_avatar', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Whoops! Updated the code to fix a couple small issues. I really must learn not to write code before my morning coffee...

Comment: So I replaced apply_filters with add_filter but nothing changes. From firebug, the default gravatar url is still being pulled.

`<img width="60" height="60" class="avatar avatar-60 photo" src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/782b5a7a555f8147ac91d84c53e5dfa2?s=60&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F1.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D60&amp;r=G" alt="">`

Comment: P.S: Just to clarify.. I replaced `get_avatar($tc->comment_author_email, $jmetc_options['avatar_size']);` with `add_filter('get_avatar', $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt);`

Comment: See updated answer. Make sure you're still calling `get_avatar()` in your template file, and passing the necessary parameters to your filter function.

Comment: @ChipBennet Don't you have to state `add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'mytheme_get_avatar', <whatever_priority>, 3 /* number of args! */ );` to actually get those arguments?

Comment: @Fronker indeed. Answer updated. (For future reference: feel free to make such corrections if/when you see that they are needed. At WPSE, community corrections/improvements are *expected*. :) )

Comment: Thanks for this little code. Because of GPDR I simply want to block every connection to third parties.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small error in above's function

better use this:

```
function mytheme_get_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size ) {
    $avatar = '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/authors/' . $id_or_email . '.jpg" alt="' . get_the_author() . '" width="' . $size . 'px" height="' . $size . 'px" />';
    return $avatar;
}
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'mytheme_get_avatar', 10, 3 );
```